# Are gnome-3-34-1804 and gnome-3-28-1804 necessary while using xfce desktop?

Tags: gnome, xfce, snap

Actually I am rather new linux user. I just changed my desktop to **xfce**, as it is lighter and uses less resources. I 'd removed the previous desktop.
Now I just checked the **snap** list and find:

- gnome-3-28-1804
- gnome-3-34-1804

Would it be any  **problem** if I **remove these two**? I am not to use gnome desktop anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Your OS & release details may be helpful.

Comment: It is the Snapcraft GNOME extension.  See https://snapcraft.io/docs/gnome-3-28-extension and https://blogs.gnome.org/hellsworth/files/2019/11/GNOME-extensions-for-desktop-apps.pdf (starting at page 9 on the second link).

Comment: @guiverc that is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Terrance  Thank you for the useful links